# Why MySQL can't start after extract the contents of the eMMC to microSD on beaglebone black?

Tags: mysql, beagleboneblack

MySQL on my beaglebone can't start.
I meet my issue after following below steps:
I want to  extract the contents of the eMMC to save off and reuse.
I used the /opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/beaglebone-black-make-microSD-flasher-from-eMMC.sh to write an image from the on-board eMMC to a microSD card.
 (Following this link http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents#Sources)
My microSD card (16Gb)

I got this error

```
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/tmp/rootfs/var/www" failed: No space left on device (28)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***

sent 11164596708 bytes  received 13752725 bytes  1434501.05 bytes/sec
total size is 13493412445  speedup is 1.21
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
writing to [/dev/mmcblk0] failed...
-----------------------------
umount: /dev/mmcblk0p1: not mounted
```

After that, all light of beagblebone is birght.

MySQL starts with this error:

```
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.
 failed!
```

Does it look like diskspace is an issue?

```
root@beaglebone:~# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  3.5G  2.4G  941M  72% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   100M  736K   99M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e807980f-6d9d-4efb-a42b-d888af80ba37  3.5G  2.4G  941M  72% /
tmpfs                                                   249M     0  249M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                   249M     0  249M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk0p1                                           96M   73M   24M  76% /boot/uboot
```

Tomcat server is started normally.

**UPDATE**:

This is logs when using **systemd-journalctl** -a cmd:

```
Jan 03 06:49:17 beaglebone mysqld[9443]: 170103  6:49:17 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in
Jan 03 06:49:17 beaglebone mysqld[9443]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2)
```

What is my problem?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After see logs:  I think my problem is missing folder.

I just create new **'/var/lib/mysql-files'**
MySQL is started.